# How to resize the disk of a Fedora guest VM in VMWare ESXi

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, fedora

How do I resize (specifically increase) the disk size of a Fedora guest VM running under VMWare ESXi 4.1?

I have a Fedora 16 VM with an lvm2 formatted disk, and I've increased its disk size using the vSphere client from 50GB to about 250GB. I rebooted the guest, and it correctly shows this size using `fdisk -l /dev/sda`. However, `df -H` still shows the old size.

I've found a few [KB articles](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1006371) explaining how to resize partitions for some flavors of Linux, but nothing for Fedora with ext4. That article seems to imply I have to create a completely new partition, and that I can't simply expand the existing partition. Using Gparted, it also prevents me from simply resizing the existing partition. Is this impossible to do under Linux?

Edit: It turns out the drive is formatted as LVM2, which apparently most Linux tools, such as GParted, don't support.

Edit: The partition in logical volume I need to resize is the root partition. Is there any way to do this without a LiveCD?

Answer (score 11):

This is a bit of a cut'n'paste of a document I wrote for internal use and although it probably over-answers your question I thought I'd put it on here in case it's of use to you or others OK.

1. Login to the machine as root or `sudo` each of the following commands, enter `fdisk –l`, you should see something like this;

   ```
   Disk /dev/sda: 21.1 GB, 21xxxxxxxxx bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
   /dev/sda2              14        2610    20860402+  8e  Linux LVM
   ```

   In this case I've altered the values but as you can see this machine has a single ~20GB root virtual disk with two partitions, sda1 and sda2, sda2 is our first LVM 'physical volume', see how LVM uses a partition type of '8e'.
2. Now type `pvdisplay`, you'll see a section for this first PV (sda2) like this;

   ```
     --- Physical volume ---
   PV Name               /dev/sda2
   VG Name               rootvg
   PV Size               19.89 GB / not usable 19.30 MB
   Allocatable           yes (but full)
   PE Size (KByte)       32768
   Total PE              636
   Free PE               0
   Allocated PE          636
   PV UUID               PgwRdY-EvCC-b5lO-Qrnx-tkrd-m16k-eQ9beC
   ```

   This shows that this second partition (sda2) is mapped to a 'volume group' called 'rootvg'.
3. Now we can increase the size of the virtual disk using the usual vSphere VSClient by selecting the VM, choosing to 'edit settings', then selecting 'Hard Disk 1'. You can then increase the 'Provisioned Size' number – so long as there are no snapshots in place anyway – and select OK. This will take a few seconds to complete.
4. If you then switch back to the Linux VM and enter

   ```
   echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hostX/scan
   ```

   where the X character is likely to be zero, it will perform a SCSI bus rescan, then run `fdisk –l`, you should see something like;

   ```
   Disk /dev/sda: 42.2 GB, 42xxxxxxxxx bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
   /dev/sda2              14        2610    20860402+  8e  Linux LVM
   ```

   You'll see that the disk size has increased, in this case to ~40GB from ~20GB but that the partition table remains the same.
5. We now need to create a new LVM partition, type `parted`, you should see something like this;

   ```
   GNU Parted 1.8.1
   Using /dev/sda
   Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
   (parted)
   ```

   You'll now need to create a new partition for the extra new space, type 'p' to see the current partition table such as this;

   ```
   Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 42.9GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition Table: msdos

   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
    1      32.3kB  107MB   107MB   primary  ext3         boot
    2      107MB   21.5GB  21.4GB  primary               lvm
   ```

   Then type `mkpart`, then select 'p' for 'Primary', for file system type enter 'ext3', for start enter a number a little higher than the combination of both 'sizes' listed above (i.e. 107MB + 21.4GB, so say 21.6GB), for end type the size of the disk (i.e. in this case 42.9GB). Once you press enter it will create this new primary partition, type 'p' to show the new partition table, you should see something like;

   ```
   Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 42.9GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition Table: msdos

   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
    1      32.3kB  107MB   107MB   primary  ext3         boot
    2      107MB   21.5GB  21.4GB  primary               lvm
    3      21.5GB  42.9GB  21.5GB  primary               ext3
   ```

   You'll see that the new partition started after the first two and fills the available space, unfortunately we had to set it to a type of 'ext3', so let's change that.
6. Type 't', then the partition number (in our case 3 as it's the third partition), then for the 'hex code' enter '8e' – once you'd done this type 'p' again and you should see it change to 'Linux LVM';

   ```
   Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
   ads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders
   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *        1          13      104391   83  Linux
   /dev/sda2           14        2610    20860402+  8e  Linux LVM
   /dev/sda3         2611        5221    20972857+  8e  Linux LVM
   ```
7. Now we need to create a new LVM 'physical volume' in this new partition, type `pvcreate /dev/sda3`, this should then create a new LVM PV called /dev/sda3, type `pvdisplay` to check;

   ```
   --- Physical volume ---
   PV Name               /dev/sda3
   VG Name              
   PV Size               20.00 GB / not usable 1.31 MB
   Allocatable           no
   PE Size (KByte)       0
   Total PE              0
   Free PE               0
   Allocated PE          0
   PV UUID               gpYPUv-XdeL-TxKJ-GYCa-iWcy-9bG6-tfZtSh
   ```

   You should see something similar to above.
8. Now we need to extend the 'rootvg Volume Group', or create a new one for non-root 'volume group', type `vgdisplay` to list all 'volume groups', here's an example;

   ```
   --- Volume group ---
   VG Name               rootvg
   System ID
   Format                lvm2
   Metadata Areas        2
   Metadata Sequence No  19
   VG Access             read/write
   VG Status             resizable
   MAX LV                0
   Cur LV                8
   Open LV               8
   Max PV                0
   Cur PV                2
   Act PV                2
   VG Size               21.3 GB
   PE Size               32.00 MB
   Total PE              1276
   Alloc PE / Size       846 / 26.44 GB
   Free  PE / Size       430 / 13.44 GB
   VG UUID               tGM4ja-k6es-la0H-LcX6-1FMY-6p2g-SRYtfY
   ```

   - If you want to extend the 'rootvg Volume Group' type `vgextend rootvg /dev/sda3`, once you press enter you should see a message saying the 'volume group' has been extended.
   - If you wanted to create a new 'volume group' you'll need to use the `vgcreate` command – probably best call me for help with that.

   Once extended enter `vgdisplay` again to see that the 'rootvg' 'volume group' has indeed been extended such as here;

   ```
   --- Volume group ---
   VG Name               rootvg
   System ID
   Format                lvm2
   Metadata Areas        2
   Metadata Sequence No  19
   VG Access             read/write
   VG Status             resizable
   MAX LV                0
   Cur LV                8
   Open LV               8
   Max PV                0
   Cur PV                2
   Act PV                2
   VG Size               39.88 GB
   PE Size               32.00 MB
   Total PE              1276
   Alloc PE / Size       846 / 26.44 GB
   Free  PE / Size       430 / 13.44 GB
   VG UUID               tGM4ja-k6es-la0H-LcX6-1FMY-6p2g-SRYtfY
   ```

   You can see the 'VG Size' is as expected.
9. Now we need to extend the 'logical volume', type `lvdisplay` to show our 'logical volumes', you'll see something like;

   ```
   --- Logical volume ---
   LV Name                /dev/rootvg/var
   VG Name                rootvg
   LV UUID                NOP1jF-09Xt-LkX5-ai4w-Srqb-xGka-nYbI2J
   LV Write Access        read/write
   LV Status              available
   # open                 1
   LV Size                3.00 GB
   Current LE             320
   Segments               3
   Allocation             inherit
   Read ahead sectors     auto
   currently set to       256
   Block device           253:2
   ```

   If we want to expand the /var file system from 3GB to 10GB then type `lvextend –L 10G /dev/rootvg/var`, now type `lvdisplay` again, you'll see the 'logical volume' has grown to 10GB;

   ```
   --- Logical volume ---
   LV Name                /dev/rootvg/var
   VG Name                rootvg
   LV UUID                NOP1jF-09Xt-LkX5-ai4w-Srqb-xGka-nYbI2J
   LV Write Access        read/write
   LV Status              available
   # open                 1
   LV Size                10.00 GB
   Current LE             320
   Segments               3
   Allocation             inherit
   Read ahead sectors     auto
   currently set to     256
   Block device           253:2
   ```
10. Now the last thing we need to do is to grow the actual file system, this doesn't have to use all of the newly added space by the way. Enter `df –h` to show the current filesystems, here's an example;

    ```
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-root
                          2.0G  1.4G  495M  74% /
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-home
                          248M  124M  113M  53% /home
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-var
                          3.0G  1.1G  1.8G  30% /var
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-usr
                          3.0G  936M  1.9G  34% /usr
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
                          3.0G  811M  2.0G  29% /opt
    ```

    If we want to expand the /var file system from 3GB to 10GB then type `resize2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-var` (or on CentOS maybe `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rootvg-var`, or similar commands depending on the type of file system).  When you press enter the actual filesystem will grow, this may take time, enter `df –h` once completed to check.

    ```
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-root
                          2.0G  1.4G  495M  74% /
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-home
                          248M  124M  113M  53% /home
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-var
                          9.88G  1.1G  8.2G  12% /var
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-usr
                          3.0G  936M  1.9G  34% /usr
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
                          3.0G  811M  2.0G  29% /opt
    ```

You're now finished!

Comment: Step 8 fails for me, when I try to run `lvextend /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root /dev/sda3`, with the error: Physical Volume "/dev/sda3" not found in Volume Group "VolGroup"

Comment: On `CentOS 7` use `xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root` instead of `resize2fs /dev/centos/root` as explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305376/resize2fs-bad-magic-number-in-super-block-while-trying-to-open

Answer (score 2):

Perform the following steps before lvextend

- **#pvcreate /dev/sda3** (to create a new physical volume, if you can't create then probably you didn't reboot after creating the partition)
- **#pvdisplay** (to check that you have created a new physical volume)
- **#vgcreate VolGroup /dev/sda3** (to assign the VolGroup to the new physical volume)
- **#lvdisplay** (to get the logical path name of the partition you want to extend)
- **#lvcreate -LxxGB -n root_new VolGroup** (to assign logical size and create a new logical volume)
- **#lvextend /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root /dev/sda3** (extend the root(if) partition finally)
- **#lvdisplay** (check the **LV** size if it has increazed or not)
- **#resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root** (to resize the actual file-system)
- **#df -h** (then check whether the actual file-system value has increazed or not)

Answer (score 0):

you have to resize it now

```
resize2fs /dev/sda
```

You must be on the 2.6 kernel do this with the file system mounted and the parameter enabled to allow online resizing.  Otherwise, you have to first unmount the device, resize, them mount the device again.

Comment: "Device or resource busy..."