# Re-sizing disk partition linux/vm

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, hard-drive, diskmanagement

I VM Player running a linux guest and I was wanting to know how do I expand the disk? In the VM player I gave more disk space but I am not sure how to mount/expand/connect the new disk space to the system.

My old disk space was 14GB

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h /
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       14G  4.5G  8.2G  36% /
```

Then I expanded it and now I see sda2 which is the new space?

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 128.8 GB, 128849018880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15665 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cd44d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        2611    20458496   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: 14.5 GB, 14537457664 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1767 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: 6408 MB, 6408896512 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 779 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Do I need to mount the new space first?

```
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root 108849018880
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The containing partition (or device) is only 3549184 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 1474836480 blocks.

 resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root 128849018880
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Invalid new size: 128849018880

[root@localhost ~]# lvextend -L+90GB /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
  Extending logical volume lv_root to 103.54 GiB
  Insufficient free space: 23040 extents needed, but only 0 available

[root@localhost ~]# lvextend -L90GB /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
  Extending logical volume lv_root to 90.00 GiB
  Insufficient free space: 19574 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

EDIT:
So after trying pvcreate/vgextend nothing has so far worked. I'm guessing the new disk space added from VM Player is not showing up?

```
pvscan
  PV /dev/sda2   VG VolGroup   lvm2 [19.51 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [19.51 GiB] / in use: 1 [19.51 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

Comment: Could you please close this question in case one of the answers was ok? If something was wrong with them please let the people know.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, you had first to resize the partition containing the logical volume, than you can proceed with LVM resize. Follow these steps:

1. with **`fdisk -l -u /dev/sda`** take note of the current partition setting (especially the start  sector)
2. **delete partition sda2 and recreate it**. *Use the very same start sector,* or you will lose your data! Obviously, *the end sector should be higher that before* (fdisk will suggest to use the last available sector by default, so you can simply press ENTER here)
3. now run **`partprobe /dev/sda`** or reboot the system. This will inform the kernel that partition size has changed
4. run **`pvresize /dev/sda2`**. This will resize the physical volume structures
5. execute **`pvs`** and **`vgs`** to check that the new size is correctly identified by LVM
6. you can now resize your LVM volume with **`lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`**
7. finally, resize the filesystem itself with **`resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`**

These instruction are valid for increasing disk space (extending the volume)

Shrinking a volume is conceptually similar but you had to follow the steps backward, starting with filesystem shrink. As a side note, if you use XFS or other filesystems that can not be shrunk, you can not resize your LVM volume without a backup/restore process.

Answer (score 0):

Since your underlying device is already extended, you should be able to see the available space in the output of `vgdisplay`. Look for the line that says `Free PE / Size`. If this is the case, you can simply extend the logical volume via `lvextend` and then grow the filesystem via `resize2fs`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a guide how to do this a while back, hope this helps.

https://serverfault.com/a/422972/1435

Answer (score 0):

I always have this guide on the side for live expanding LVM

http://www.scribd.com/doc/39997149/Live-Expand-RedHat-based-Linux-LVM-Volume-and-Filesystem-on-VMWare-Virtual-Machines

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you put the LVM (physical volume) into a partition.

If it were on the device directly, you could simply do

```
* pvextend
* lvextend
* resize2fs
```

In your case you will have to boot using a live-cd or such delete the `/dev/sda2` partition and recreate with a bigger size then proceed as outlined above

The **safer way** would however be to

create a new volume for your VM which would then be `/dev/sdb` for example
 initialize it as a PV using pvcreate
 add the new PV to the existing volume group

```
vgextend my_volume_group /dev/sdb
```

now you can extend the logical volume

```
lvextend -v -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

and finally the filesystem

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Once you aware of the all the layers (physical disk, partition, physical volume, volume group, logical volume) it will be a piece of cake.