# Adding disks to and resizing a LVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, lvm, ubuntu-12.04

I'm managing a virtual cloud server on EC2 for a client which has the requirement of expandable storage. Currently, I have a 1TB EBS drive mounted at `/mnt` which I need to expand. Since 1TB is the limit on EBS drive size, I need a way to seamlessly merge multiple drives into one large virtual drive, hence LVM2.

As far as I understand, LVM can accomplish what I need, but I'm not sure as to how to get started. I need to know how to do the following:

1. Create a new LVM group "from scratch."
2. Add another disk or partition to it.
3. Expand the filesystem online if possible.

Resizing the filesystem seems to be pretty straightforward, but I'm not exactly so keen on working with LVM.

How can I setup a LVM array with a single disk (1), and then subsequently add another disk to it, increasing its size (2), and then resize the filesystem on it to fill the disk (3)? I'd like to use ext3 or ext4 if possible.

Comment: Have you considered something like Gluster?

Comment: I believe that this question has been asked and answered at least a few times....have you checked the archives here or on the Linux SE, or even the SuperUser SE?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a basic question for here as the site's generally for more advanced sysadmins but [HERE](https://serverfault.com/a/422972/1435) is a previous answer of mine to a similar question that you should be able to alter to fit your needs.