# VMWare ESXi: to extend a partition or create a new drive?

Tags: redhat, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, lvm, io

Is it better to extend an existing partition or to create a new drive in a VMWare ESXi virtual machine? I'll be using LVM to put the drive in an existing volume group on my VM and to extend a SAN mount point. Which would be better to do and why?

Comment: What kind of VMware product are you using?

Comment: I'll be using ESXi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a small amount, say taking a 50GB disk up to 75GB then we just extend and LVM. If it's the same size of more then I'd be tempted to add a new disk. Obviously one of the reasons is that if you have two disks of the same size you can let StorageDRS look at their RW profiles and move them to the appropriate storage type automatically - you can't if it's just extended, but extending is quick and easy.

Oh and if you look at my previous answers you'll find I did a 'how to' guide for extending disks in this way, every command etc.

edit - [HERE](https://serverfault.com/a/422972/1435) you go

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you use LVM it is probably better to create new disk.

Comment: Could you explain how it would be faster? Thanks.

Comment: Do you seriously suggest to make VMs cause accesses on as many physical disks as possible? With a fixed number of disks and this as the policy for **all** VMs?