# Increasing the size of a partition on a virtual Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, partition

I'm a web developer who's been put in charge of a small virtualised web server at work. Unfortunately, I've never done anything to do with server admin before, so I'm a little lost.

The guy in charge of the virtual machines has increased the size of the virtual hardware, and I've attempted to follow several guides on how to increase the space using LVM, but I've gotten a little lost with it, and am worried I've messed it up a bit.

fdisk -l displays the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e6ec9

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    52426751    25962497    5  Extended
/dev/sda3          499712      501757        1023   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda5          501760    52426751    25962496   8e  Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/TBD--WEB1-root: 9403 MB, 9403629568 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1143 cylinders, total 18366464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/TBD--WEB1-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/TBD--WEB1-swap_1: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2088 cylinders, total 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/TBD--WEB1-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

and df -h displays:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/TBD--WEB1-root  8.7G  7.3G  979M  89% /
udev                        7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       3.2G  244K  3.2G   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                   228M  221M     0 100% /boot
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [THIS](https://serverfault.com/a/422972/1435) previous answer of mine - it may not fit the bill perfectly but should outline the basic steps required to get the job done.

Comment: After looking around a bit more, I'm not so sure that the mounted file system is actually using LVM unfortunately. I think that the main filesystem is the one that `fdisk -l` listed as `/dev/mapper/TBD--WEB1-root`. I increased the size of /dev/sda2 as an experiment, so I have 'found' the extra disk space, I just now have no idea how to actually use it as part of the main file system.

Comment: Oh well, just thought I'd throw that out there as it sometimes helps

Comment: Finally got there - although your answer didn't get me there directly, it helped immensely! Thank you