# Need to expand LV and partition LUN

Tags: linux, storage, lvm, parted

I am fairly new with this.

I read many about expanding to the back of the current partition but 
how do I expand partition to the front of the disk.  I need to keep the data on it as it is 1/4 part of a striped LV. Also the storage on a IBM DS3512 SAN.

I'm running the commands on 1 of the HA nodes that connect to the SAN.

currently
    # parted /dev/sdi
    GNU Parted 2.1
    (parted) print
    Model: IBM 1746 FAStT (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdi: 10.2TB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: gpt

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 4      5304GB  9438GB  4179GB                      lvm
```

I want this drive to use the full 10TB for this partition so I can expand PV and LV. I read gparted allowed expanding the partition to the front but the server has no gui so I could not run gparted.

Comment: This is two questions - the LVM bit is easy(ish) - I did a guide to it a few years ago, might be a bit out of date but have a look (http://serverfault.com/a/422972/1435) - the SAN one really depends on how things are setup - we'd need more details.

Comment: Thank you! It seems your guide adds a new partition to the disk. I would prefer to expand the current one so I don't have to deal with extra PV etc. but I will keep this bookmarked and go this way if there is no easy way to expand the partition.

Comment: If you read it again you'll see how to just expand it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a new partition using @Chopper3 's guide.