# How to extend disk space in the current partition (with cmdlets)

Tags: centos, centos7, disk-space-utilization

I have my current partition disk space (found at /dev/mapper/cl-root) set at 50Go on my CentOS server. I want to extend the current disk space (to become 500Go) used in a neat way with commands.

How to do it ?

UPDATE  : `parted -l lsblk` returns /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc actual sizes and other infos.
But what i want is to extend the root partition under /dev/mapper/cl-root which is listed among others with `fdisk -l` cmd
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `LVM` used and which filesystem is the partition formatted with? Send the output of `parted -l`, `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,fssize,mountpoint,model,vendor`, `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs` commands.

Comment: I will update my answer with the output of that command shortly.

Comment: i don't think it's LVM based partitions though, filesystem must be FAT32 i guess.

Comment: File system unallocated.

Comment: Since you've got `/dev/mapper/cl-root` LVM is used. Copy - paste the output of the 5 commands in my first comment if you want to get help.

Comment: @Krakout pls see UPDATE

Comment: Why have you posted screenshots of text? You should post the text instead.

Comment: yes sorry for that, hope it will do.

Comment: What a mix and match of disks :) Your first disk, 900GB: Is it really not used or does it have something very exotic (and incomprehensible) installed? Your `/home` volume is LVM RAID residing on a part of the 2nd and on the 3rd disk. So, how do you want to proceed? `sdb` where `/` resides has no more space available. If `sda`, 1st disk, is really empty, you can use this to add space on `/` using LVM. There are alternates, shrinking `/home` for example if `ext4` is used (you added spaces on `lsblk` command so the full info is not provided). But they involve much more work to be done.

Comment: I myself was thinking of creating a partition (and mount it?) from `/dev/sda` (that of 900Go) and add that new partition of PV to the VG of `cl` and extend `/dev/sdb3/cl-root` LV with that amount added . So the first cited option is good i think. Please show me the steps with the cmds to use tailored to my case. Thanks.
PS : the first disk is unallocated space nothing installed on it and can be used of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After evaluating the output of commands and the comments, you need:
*(execute these commands as a sudoer user, adding sudo in front or as root)*

```
parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt
parted -a opt /dev/sda mkpart lvm 0% 50%
pvcreate /dev/sda1
vgextend cl /dev/sda1
lvextend -r -l 100%VG cl/root
```

Comment: ok thanks, and no `xfs_global` or `resize2fs` needed in the end ?

Comment: `-r` on lvextend does this, resizes filesystem.

Comment: Alright i will try this thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic answer I gave a few years back, most if not all of it should still work;

[How to resize the disk of a Fedora guest VM in VMWare ESXi](https://serverfault.com/questions/422930/how-to-resize-the-disk-of-a-fedora-guest-vm-in-vmware-esxi/422972#422972)

Comment: sry it's not helping